# Get a boolean from test expression

Tags: bash, shell-script, test

I have this bash code:

```
   local r2g_keep_temp=$(r2g_match_arg "--keep" "${my_args[@]}");
   local r2g_multi_temp=$(r2g_match_arg "--multi" "${my_args[@]}");

   local r2g_multi=[ "$r2g_multi_temp" || "$r2g_keep_temp" ];
```

I just want r2g_multi to represent a boolean, if either $r2g_multi_temp or $r2g_keep_temp is defined. How can I do that? The above is syntactically invalid.

On the other hand, this is syntactically valid, but not sure if it's correct:

```
local r2g_multi=$("$r2g_multi_temp" || "$r2g_keep_temp");
```

Comment: looks good to me, thx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no booleans in the shell scripts.

Best simulation for them are integer values.
For example, `0` for `true` and `1` for `false`.

`[[ -v variable_name ]]` will return `1` if the `variable_name` **was not** defined or `0` if it **was**.

Therefore, you can get your desired behavior with this:

```
// If one of the variables is defined, return value of this command is 0.
[[ -v r2g_keep_temp ]] || [[ -v r2g_multi_temp ]]

// Save the return value of the last command (0 or 1).
local r2g_multi="$?"
```

Of courese, you can interpret the numbers however you like, I just wanted to demonstrate one example.

---

By the way,

```
local r2g_multi=$("$r2g_multi_temp" || "$r2g_keep_temp");
```

is not the thing that you wish.

1. First the variables `r2g_multi_temp` and `r2g_keep_temp` will be replaced by their values.
2. Now the subshell will try to execute the value of the `r2g_multi_temp`.
3. If by some miracle that value is a valid bash command there are 2 cases:

   - That command is executed succesfully and its `stdout` is saved in the `r2g_multi`.
   - That command failed and subshell invoked the value of the `r2g_multi_temp`.
     Similar story again, if it is a valid command it will be executed and its `stdout` will be **appended** on the possible `stdout` of the command executed from the value of `r2g_keep_temp` and everything will be stored in `r2g_multi`.

All in all, run away from this :D

Comment: nice, what's the difference between `-n $foo` and `-v $foo`? I just heard of using -n to check if a variable is non empty

Comment: "0" and "1" are both defined though, so I need to return either "" or "1" not "0" and "1"

Comment: `foo=""`, for this variable `-n $foo` will return `1` while `-v foo` (note that there is no `$`) will return `0`. I don't understand the second quetion, can you explain it a bit more?

Comment: nevermind, I was just confused between -v -z -n